# Building a list from a non-traversable without recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, enums, traversable

I can build a data structure that is a member of the `Traversable` typeclass (e.g. `List` or `Map`), by mapping (`map`, `mapM`) or folding (`foldl`, `foldM`) another traversable data structure.

However, I often encounter situations where I need to build a traversable data structure with a member of the `Num` typeclass (e.g. `Integer`).

My usual approach here is to build a list by using a recursive operation - for example:

```hs
foo :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
foo n fs
  | m < 2 = fs
  | rem m 2 == 0 = foo (m - 1) (m:fs)
  | otherwise = foo (m - 1) fs
  where m = abs n
```

This function returns the absolute values of the integers that are divisible by two, and are between 2 and n (inclusive).

Using the above example, is there an idiomatic way to build a list from a non-traversable without using recursion?

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? Is it to rewrite your `foo` function without using recursion? Can you explain in english what the `foo` function is supposed to do?

Comment: `foldr` can generate a lost for foldable data structures. For example a simple way to perform a `toList` on an arbitrary `Foldable` data structure is `foldr (:) []`.

Comment: @Aplet123 Broadly I want to understand how to approach this class of problems without using recursion, using this as an example - but yes the goal here is also to rewrite the specific example function `foo`. Will update question to explain what the function does.

Comment: This particular function can be written non-recursively as `\n fs -> [2,4..n] ++ fs` but there's no way to perform such a transformation on some general function without knowing what the function does. For less trivial functions, it may be more difficult to make them non-recursive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for a way to build a list from a non-traversable object without using recursion, but I don't think this is *really* what you want.  After all, any traversal is going to *use* recursion — how do you think `map` and `foldl` are implemented?  I think the more precise question you're asking is whether there's a well-known function or built-in way to express a so-called "numeric fold" where the recursion is "behind the scenes", or implicit, instead of explicit as in your `foo` example.

Well, one simple way to achieve this is to write a `foldNum` function yourself.  For instance:

```hs
foldNum :: Num n => (n -> a -> a) -> n -> a
foldNum f n = f n (foldNum f (n - 1))
```

Then, you can define `foo` as:

```hs
foo :: Integer -> [Integer]
foo = reverse . foldNum go . abs
  where
    go n a | n < 2        = []
           | rem n 2 == 0 = n:a
           | otherwise    = a
```

---

If you're a little disappointed with this, I understand why: you haven't really saved much by using this definition of `foldNum`.  In fact, the definition I give above *doesn't even have a built-in base case*.  The problem with folding a number is that there are lots of ways to do it!  You can subtract or add any amount on each step, and there's no clear place to stop (zero might seem a natural place to stop, but that's only true for non-negative numbers).  One way to proceed is to try to make our `foldNum` *even more* generic.  How about:

```hs
foldNum :: (n -> a -> a) -> (n -> Bool) -> (n -> n) -> a -> n -> a
foldNum f stop step a n
  | stop n = a
  | otherwise = foldNum f stop step (f n a) (step n)
```

Now, we can write `foo` as:

```hs
foo :: Integer -> [Integer]
foo = foldNum (\x a -> if even x then x:a else a) (< 2) (subtract 1) [] . abs
```

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

---

Footnote:
Just as lists can be folded left or right (`foldl` and `foldr`), soo too can we fold numbers in two different ways.  You can see this by replacing the last line of the above `foldNum` definition with::

```hs
  | otherwise = f n $ foldNum f stop step a (step n)
```

For instance, for `foo` the difference between these two is the order of the resulting list.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Is there any reading material that you would recommend on this topic?

Comment: I don't have any links on hand to suggest, but a keyword I would suggest looking up is "catamorphism".  A catamorphism is a generalization of the idea of a fold.  A search for "fold catamorphism" turned up a couple of decent looking blog posts.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're going from 2 to n, and filtering out values, use the `filter` function designed just for this:

```hs
foo :: Integer -> [Integer]
foo n = filter (\x -> x `mod` 2 == 0) [2..n]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is the library function `unfoldr` from `Data.List`.  It has signature:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

It generates a list `[a]` from a value of type `b` which can be non-traversable.  It operates by repeatedly applying its first argument to the `b` value to get a fresh `a` value to add to the list and an updated `b` value for the next call, until it gets `Nothing` which ends the list.

Note that it doesn't allow you to skip certain `b`s without generating any `a`s or let you generate multiple `a`s for a single `b`.  However, you can work around that limitation by returning a list of lists and then concatenating.  So, your `foo` example would look like:

```
foo = concat . unfoldr step
  where step n | m < 2 = Nothing  -- time to stop
               | rem m 2 == 0 = Just ([m], m-1)  -- return one element
               | otherwise    = Just ([], m-1)   -- return no elements
          where m = abs n
```

In many more realistic scenarios, you don't need to `concat` lists of lists.  For example:

```
import Data.List

bar :: Int -> [[Int]]
bar n = unfoldr step 1
  where step k | k > n     = Nothing
               | otherwise = Just (replicate k k, k + 2)

main = do
  print $ bar 10
  -- [[1],[3,3,3],[5,5,5,5,5],[7,7,7,7,7,7,7],[9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]]
```